# Plotting 3D Data from Gyro Encoder

Tags: python, serial-port, gyroscope

I am collecting data from the gyro encoder via serial port. I would like to plot the real time data. Below is the python code:

import serial
import struct
import numpy as np

```
#import csv
ser = serial.Serial("COM5",115200)
buffer = []
while 1:
        buffer += ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        '\x7e\x5d' in 'buffer'
        val = ser.read(18)
        (NA, timestamp, rsvd, gyro_xout, gyro_yout, gyro_zout, level, encoder_angle) =   struct.unpack(">HHhhhhlh",val)
        print (NA, timestamp, rsvd, gyro_xout, gyro_yout, gyro_zout, level, encoder_angle)
```

I want to plot gyro_xout, gyro_yout, and gyro_zout. I am new to python. I would greatly appreciate if someone can help in plotting the 3D values. Thanks!!